# Split the [ape] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The description for [ape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ape) is

> "APE is a full-featured open source solution designed for Ajax push.
>   It includes a webserver and a JavaScript framework. APE allows to
>   implement any kind of real-time data streaming to a web browser,
>   without having to install anything on the client-side. "

Yet 10 out of the 15 question currently on the front page of the tag refer to the popular `R` package for phylogenetics, `ape`. There is currently no tag for the `ape` `R` package, but it certainly seems like there is a demand for one.

The simple solution seems to retag the `R` questions with an [ape-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ape-r) or [ape-phylo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ape-phylo) tag